# javax.jms.Destination - Dynamically update the defaultDestination

Tags: spring, jms

I have a requirement where i need to populate the Receiver Queue Names dynamically by polling a Database table.
Framework used - Spring Integration,
Messaging Router - Solace

**Issue Faced -** 
Need to pass the queue name (polled from the DB) as javax.jms.Destination to the Jms Template.

The code below is the Service Activator class where i trigger the jmsTemplate to read from the queue and pass to the next flow.

```
public class JmsTemplateListener {

    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
            this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JmsTemplateListener.class);

    public Message<?> messageDetails(Message<?> message) {

            Message<?> inboundMessage = null;

            try {

                    String receiverQueueName = (String) message.getHeaders().get(
                                    "receiverQueueName");
                    logger.info("receiverQueueName -- " + receiverQueueName);

                    Destination destination = jmsTemplate.getDefaultDestination();
                    logger.info("Queue Name - " + destination);

                    // This is where i want to replace the DefaultDestination with receiverQueueName
                    //polled from the database

                    // But unable to convert or cast from String to Javax.jms.Destination

                    logger.info("Calling JMS Tempate Receive() method");
                    SolTextMessage receivedMessage = (SolTextMessage) jmsTemplate
                                    .receive(jmsTemplate.getDefaultDestination());

                    logger.info("Message Retreived from Receiver Queue using JMS Tempalte :\n"
                                    + receivedMessage.getText());
                    inboundMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(
                                    receivedMessage.getText()).build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return inboundMessage;
    }
```

Can somebody guide me how to change the default destination to the one i poll from the database?

Any JMS Utility is available that i'm not aware about, which can take a String as input and update the destination to read from?

Regards,
  PD

Answer (score 2):

And why would you need to set the default destination for that? If you want to have multithreading problems, this is the way to go but I doubt that is what you want.

Nextwhy should it even be a `javax.jms.Destination`? Simply configure the correct implementation (or your own) of a `DestinationResolver` which resolves the name to an actual `javax.jms.Destination`. Saves you a lot of headaches and multithread problems. Instead of calling the `receive(Destination)` method call the `receive(String)` method (which will take care of the Destination lookup/resolve whatever).

But please don't mess around with the `defaultDestination` as that will only give you more problems that you are trying to solve right now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all please check the solution for the above is :

```
        <bean id="SolaceJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate" 
            lazy-init="default" autowire="default"> 
            <property name="environment"> 
                    <map> 
                            <entry key="java.naming.provider.url" value="${java.naming.provider.url}" /> 
                            <entry key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="${java.naming.factory.initial}" /> 
                            <entry key="java.naming.security.credentials" value="${java.naming.security.credentials}" /> 
                            <entry key="java.naming.security.principal" value="${java.naming.security.principal}" /> 
                            <entry key="Solace_JMS_VPN" value="${solace.jms.vpn}" /> 
                    </map> 
            </property> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="SolaceCachedConnectionFactory" 
            class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"> 
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="SolaceConnectionFactory" /> 
            <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" /> 
    </bean> 


    <bean id="SolaceConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" 
            lazy-init="default" autowire="default"> 
            <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="SolaceJndiTemplate" /> 
            <property name="jndiName" value="${int.dbus.jms.outbound.connectionfactory}" /> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
            class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager"> 
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="SolaceCachedConnectionFactory" /> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="SimpleDestinationResolver" 
            class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver" /> 


    <bean id="inboundJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"> 
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="SolaceCachedConnectionFactory" /> 
            <!-- <property name="defaultDestination" ref="inboundDestination" /> --> 
            <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" /> 
            <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true" /> 
            <property name="deliveryMode" value="2" /> 
            <property name="destinationResolver" ref="SimpleDestinationResolver" /> 
    </bean>         


    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"> 
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="SolaceCachedConnectionFactory" /> 
            <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true" /> 
            <property name="deliveryMode" value="2" /> 
            <property name="destinationResolver" ref="SimpleDestinationResolver" /> 
    </bean> 

    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter 
            jms-template="jmsTemplate" channel="com.db.jms.outbound" destination-expression="headers.senderQueueName" > 
    </int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Regards Ravindar Nidigonda